# With statement and SQLalchemy engine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I try to implement SQLalchemy engine using following construction

```
with sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///my_db.sqlite") as engine:
     (do something)
```

I get an error: `AttributeError: __exit__`

What is wrong? And how can I explicitly close my SQLalchemy engine?

Comment: It seems that the `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` return class does not implement the `__exit__` magic method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A SQLAlchemy engine is not a context manager, so it can't be used in a `with` statement. It manages the connections in a pool for you, see the documentation on [`engine.execute()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute) and [`engine.dispose()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.dispose) for an explanation of how.